# How do I step into a function called in a return value when debugging with rust-gdb?

Tags: debugging, rust, gdb

In the following code:

```
match fnA(size) {
    Some(arr) => SomeBlock::new(size, &arr, false).as_ptr().add(1) as *mut c_void,
    None => ptr::null::<c_void>() as *mut c_void,
}
```

I want to use `rust-gdb` to step into `SomeBlock::new(size, &arr, false)`. When I run it normally, I am able to step into `fnA`, but if I try to step when I'm on the line with `Some(arr)`, `gdb` just ends up running the rest of the program and exiting.

I know I can directly insert a breakpoint at `SomeBlock::new`, but I was curious if there was a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the GDB [documentation on Rust](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Rust.html):

> The Rust expression evaluator does not support “statement-like” expressions such as `if` or `match`, or lambda expressions.

It seems that you cannot step into anything that is inside a `match` expression. Note that you can step into `fnA` as it is evaluated before its output gets matched inside the match block.